# SUbviews are not displayed when run in device

Tags: iphone, view, subviews

GoodMorning All!!!

I am creating subviews of UIViews of small dimensions and adding it to the view using the statement [self.view addSubView:myview]; in the viewDidLoad method,when i run the application in the simulator its displaying the subviews created,but when i run the same in the device the subviews are not getting displayed.

My subviews are not empty they have labels on them,i see them on the simulator ,but when i run the same in the device the screen is empty.

I am using Xcode 3.2.4 and the device OS is 4.1.

Please give me solution to this issue as soon as you people can.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning before running the application and if still it gets displayed on simulator and not on device then just try bringing the subviews to front.

```
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:your_subview];
```

hAPPY iCODING...

Comment: Getting a vote and accepting the answer is the best way to thanks :P

Answer (score 1):

Try to set background color of your subviews to confirm that your views are added to main view.

may be you have forget to copy images to the resources folder or like that.